# socket.io infinite loop python/js continus data

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, flask, socket.io

I'm stuck using socket.io (flask)

my frotend js:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        namespace = '/test'; 
        var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
        socket.on('connect', function() {
            socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
            $('#status').append('connected');
        });
        function eye_pos() {
            socket.emit('eye', function (msg) {
                var tit = $('#tit')[0];
                console.log(msg);
                tit.style.display = 'block';
                tit.style.left = (msg['x']) + 'px';
                tit.style.top = (msg['y']) + 'px';
                });
        }
        while ($('#status').text() === 'connected'){
            eye_pos();
        }
```

my backend python:

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    print('socet_connected')
    global tracker
    tracker = EyeTribe()
    tracker.connect()
    tracker.pushmode()

@socketio.on('eye', namespace='/test')
def test_message():
    n = tracker.next()
    x = str(n.raw).split(';')
    y = x[0] if int(x[1]) >= 0 else x[1]*(-1)
    x = x[1] if int(x[0]) >= 0 else x[0]*(-1)
    print('feye', x, y)
    return {'x': x, 'y': y}
```

This code works great if it is not in a loop (in js) but after inserting it in a loop (like above) the python code loops over it self and send data which doesn't get to the js (there is no console.log event even), and closing the site does not stop the python loop.
Slowing the loop with setInterval does not work as well.

Comment: What is the error ? and what is the purpose of this code ?

Comment: The error is that the python starts infinite loop and does not emit data or JS does not receive it, first I thought that it may be too long for backend to send a respond but the problem exists even when I setInterval for 1000ms.
As stated above it works properly without the loop.
The purpose of the code is to receive data from backend which is connected to eye tracker. This is the client ask-recive version, now I'm trying one using only receive version only client side.